# Spring Boot Resilience4J: Unresolved dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resilience4j

I am trying to implement Resilience4j in a sample application and I was following the [demo](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo/blob/master/build.gradle) application from the official documentation. But adding the below dependencies gives me a gradle error:

```
Unresolved dependency: org.springframework.cloud spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.thomsoncodes'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
}
ext{
    resilience4jVersion = '1.7.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:${resilience4jVersion}")
    compile("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-all:${resilience4jVersion}") // Optional, only required when you want to use the Decorators class
    compile("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:${resilience4jVersion}")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by using spring-cloud in your project, too. spring-cloud's bom is adding spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-dependencies-x.y.z.pom into your classpath defining its own dependency for resilience4j. At the time of my investigation spring-cloud version 2021.0.5 defines still resilience4j.version 1.7.0.

The issue was already reported in an older post here: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/848

If you want to use a more recent version of resilience4j you can overwrite the dependency imports in build.gradle on your own or exclude the imports originating from spring-cloud.

For me utilizing Maven instead of Gradle adding another dependency for resilience4j-bom solved the issue.

```
<properties>
  <resilience4j.version>2.0.2</resilience4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>resilience4j-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the version to 1.7.0. I have had the similar error some days ago. For some reason there seems to be a problem with transitive dependencies related to the spring-boot2 artifact. The artifact itself is in the version 1.7.1 but all transitive dependencies are 1.7.0.

After the change all versions were then 1.7.0 and it worked.